# MVC4 model binding - Passing Custom View Models & values from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed view with the following model.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public List<ProductOptionWithValues> ProductOptionsWithValues { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOptionWithValues
{
    public ProductOption ProductOption;
    public List<AllowedOptionValue> AllowedOptionValues;
}
```

I'm using this Model To populate a form where a user can select the options they want for a product.
This is the view.

```
@model AsoRock.Entities.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <h3> 
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Product.ProductName)

        ----> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Product.Price) 
    </h3>
    <br/>

    foreach (var item in Model.ProductOptionsWithValues)
    {
        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductOption.Option.OptionName)</b>
        <br/>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductOptionsWithValues, 
                new SelectList(item.AllowedOptionValues, 
                "Id", "DisplayString", 
                item.AllowedOptionValues.First().Id))
        <br/>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
}
```

In my controller I am trying to pass the model back. When I set a break point in the controller it hits it but the Product view model is empty, any ideas how I can get the values that are selected in the view back in to my controller?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ProductViewModel ProductViewModel)
{
    return View();
    //return View();
}
```

Comment: Change your model name to `public ActionResult Details(ProductViewModel model)` and check.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to change the name of the viewmodel parameter from `ProductViewModel` to something else e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ProductViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

Now it's very odd that the `viewModel` param is not set to an instance of the class. The MVC model binder will still create an instance of `ProductViewModel` even if none of it's properties are set to anything. You're not using a custom model binder by any chance?

Also I would very strongly suggest that your viewmodel class does not have a `Product` property. Instead, create properties in the viewmodel specifically for the `Product` properties you intend to use e.g.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public List<ProductOptionWithValues> ProductOptionsWithValues { get; set; }
}
```

Using `Product` in the viewmodel sort of defeats the point of having a viewmodel. The viewmodel should contain only the bare minimum that the view needs. Including `Product` means the viewmodel is now bloated with extra data it does not use/need.

EDIT:

In your shoes, I would strip down the view itself, using only little bits of the viewmodel, and POST to the controller to see what happens. If the viewmodel calss is not NULL, go back to the view and add another bit back. Keep doing this until the viewmodel is NULL again. Doing this bit by bit should help.

Comment: No I am not using any custom bindings, you said I should not have the product class inside my productviewmodel, I'm not sure I agree. I am using every property of my product class in my view. I have changed the name of the parameter in the post method, it is still null when I hit the break point...ideally what I want back when there is a post is the same object I passed to the view, but with some indication of what options where selected from the N number of drop down lists in the view.

Comment: Ahh OK, it wasn't clear in the code, but if you are using everything associated with the ``Product`, then in that case passing it as part of the viewmodel makes sense.

Comment: Just got back on the computer... gona have a crack at it... but still getting back null at the moment.